# How to filter (grep) output of a process in Procfile?

Tags: foreman, procfile

I have a Procfile which looks like that:

```
electron: ./node_modules/.bin/electron .
```

I would like to remove all the lines whith `_rawLocationToUILocation` from the output. I've tried the following:

```
electron: sh -c './node_modules/.bin/electron . 2>&1 | grep -v rawLocationToUILocation'
```

but after that, all output is removed. I thought it could be linked to buffering so I used `unbuffer` but that did not change anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. It was indeed related to buffering.

Using the `--line-buffered` option of grep resolved the problem.